# How do I get all values of end string when finding the values between two strings

Tags: linux, sed

I am using sed to find all the values between two strings.

My command:

```
cat file.txt | sed "/string1/,/string2/p"
```

This command works however, string two has multiple instances. This command only gets the first instances. For example:

file.txt:

1. aaa
2. xxx
3. www
4. rrr
5. rrr

If I were to use my command on this file, it would get:

1. aaa
2. xxx
3. www
4. rrr

How would I go about this?

Comment: The sed program shown does not produce the output shown. Did you forget to include `-n`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a 'simple' solution to this task using `sed`, but if you only have one "pattern1" and multiple "pattern2's", you could process the file in reverse (i.e. from the last line to the first line) and use `sed '/pattern2/,/pattern1/'` to capture your desired lines, then reverse the output again, e.g.

```
cat file.txt
don't capture this line
aaa
xxx
www
rrr
capture this line
rrr
don't capture this line

tac file.txt | sed -n '/rrr/,/aaa/p' | tac
aaa
xxx
www
rrr
capture this line
rrr
```

This works for multiple occurrences of pattern2. Would that solve your problem? Or is your actual use-case more complicated than the minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/aaa/{:a;h;:b;$bc;n;/rrr/!{H;bb};x;p;x;ba;:c;x;P}' file
```

This solution will print nothing before `aaa` and at least one occurrence of `rrr`. Subsequent lines printed will only be between `rrr` and `rrr` until the end of file.

Another solution will print between `aaa` and the `rrr` where the `rrr` is the last such occurrence before the end of file or another occurrence of `aaa`.

```
sed -n '/aaa/{:a;h;:b;$bc;n;/aaa/{x;/rrr/P;x;ba};/rrr/!{H;bb};x;p;x;ba;:c;x;P}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '
    # skip input until first RE1 found
    /RE1/!d

    # then loop printing lines until RE2 found
:a
    p
    n
    /RE2/!ba

    # then loop printing lines until RE2 *not* found
:b
    p
    n
    //bb

' <file.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide the correct output - on my system it only captures the lines from "aaa" to the first "rrr" - sorry @jhnc

Comment: @jared_mamrot I consider input like `----axwrrrrr-----axwrr----` not `----axwrcccr---axwrcr---`